# Can't import module installed with pip (anaconda python)

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I'm trying to use the [ReadIM](https://bitbucket.org/fleming79/readim/src/master/) package with an anaconda environment (anaconda 4.7.12, python 3.8, pip 19.3.1), thus requiring me to use `pip install readIM` which succeeds, with the package found in `conda list` and `pip list`.

I have read a lot of posts talking about using the correct python and pip paths, my `python where` shows only my anaconda path, where I ran `conda install pip` beforehand, and then `pip -V` shows my pip is in my conda path.

I have tried `conda update --all` and `pip uninstall readIM`. I also read that it could be an issue with Jupyter notebook, hence in the conda command prompt I tried `python` then `import readIM`, which still gave me the same import error.

As advised on the source page, I tried installing by running `python setup.py build install`/`python setup.py install` in the source directory, however this gave me an error

> cygwin TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'

I am at a loss, any ideas?

Thanks,
Mustafa.

UPDATE:

Managed to compile it from source successfully, but still get the same error:

> (base) C:>python -m pip install ReadIM-0.8.2.tar.gz
>   Processing c:\readim-0.8.2.tar.gz
>   Building wheels for collected packages: ReadIM
>     Building wheel for ReadIM (setup.py) ... done
>     Created wheel for ReadIM: filename=ReadIM-0.8.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl size=219546 sha256=90f8960a6f1f80ae62dc18eab4bcd31fb2a6dfd7da364a5c15fc37e6e2ce0360
>     Stored in directory: C:\Users\mi4517\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\d6\a9\11\936e986255027bb654601b322a3431f9bcc3fde72ebb406835
>   Successfully built ReadIM
>   Installing collected packages: ReadIM
>   Successfully installed ReadIM-0.8.2
>
> (base) C:>python
>   Python 3.7.5 (default, Oct 31 2019, 15:18:51) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
> > > import readIM
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'readIM'>

Following their instructions (`python setup.py build install` then `python setup.py test`) yields a successful build but a failed test:

> C:\ReadIM-0.8.2>python setup.py test
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "setup.py", line 41, in 
>       assert os.path.isdir(testFileDir)
>   AssertionError

**SOLUTION**

It was installing correctly, just that I was **importing it incorrectly** in Python. I was doing `import readIM` or `import readim` when it should be `import ReadIM` I did not know it was case sensitive!

Thank you for your help, apologies for the trivial mistake on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was installing correctly, just that I was importing it incorrectly in Python. I was doing import readIM or import readim when it should be import ReadIM I did not know it was case sensitive!

Thank you for your help, apologies for the trivial mistake on my part.

Answer (score 8):

I had faced a similar issue. With your conda environment activated, type

```
which pip
```

Check if it shows the path to pip in your environment. In my case, it was not. It was showing path to some other pip. So `pip install` was installing in that environment. To fix use the full path of pip, like below

```
~/anaconda3/envs/my_env/bin/pip install ...
```

Comment: I'm using Windows 10, when I type `which pip` in the anaconda prompt it says it is not a recognised command. `where pip` works, yielding:

`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\pip.exe` as a lone result

Comment: Okay. I'm not that familiar with windows. This path doesn't look like your environment pip, right? Can you see if a pip file is present in your environment directory? Like in `...\anaconda3\envs\my_env\pip.exe`

Comment: Using a virtual environment, I do see my pip.exe in such a location:
`(ReadIMEnv) C:\>where pip
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\ReadIMEnv\Scripts\pip.exe`

Comment: Okay. Instead of `pip install`, can you try `...\anaconda3\envs\my_env\pip.exe install ...`

Comment: Ran it, installed fine. Tried it in python, still an import error :(

`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\ReadIMEnv\Scripts\pip.exe install readIM`

Comment: Oh :( bad luck. One more thing. You're using Python 3.8 right? It was released recently. Are you sure your module is supported with python 3.8? Can you try with a lower version of python? Like 3.6 or 3.7?

Comment: Tried 3.6.9, 3.7.0, 3.7.5 (and 3.8), yet still no luck :( Although, when I do `where readIM` it can't find it, even though it's found on `conda list`, this could be part of the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203342/discussion-between-nagabhushan-s-n-and-mustafa-iqbal).

Answer (score 4):

To avoid this issue follow these steps

1. open Anaconda prompt
2. type this command `conda install -c conda-forge imread`
3. after installation open jupiter notebook.
4. type `import imread` then run.

Comment: Hi Kalana,

thanks for your reply, I would love to install directly from conda, however this package (ReadIM, not imread) is not available on conda.

Comment: Is this patch or something I have never heard about `ReadIM `

Comment: It's used to read .im7 and .vc7 files in python (otherwise only possible using proprietary software or MatLAB), see the page [here](https://bitbucket.org/fleming79/readim/src/master/).